# Inbox by Google doesn't update unless opened

Tags: iphone, gmail

Despite being setup to allow background refresh, Inbox does not notify of new emails unless I manually open the app. How can I fix this?

Comment: It does not notify of new email but it is already downloaded or it is downloaded when you open the app? Also, is "Low power mode" on?

Comment: No low power. I open it and I have to refresh the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings > Inbox and check that it is allowed to access Background App Refresh and  Cellular Data